# Why my recursive function calling itself again after returning the value in c#?

Tags: c#, function, recursion

I have function in C#, this is :

```
public int checkUplinkID(string memID, string original_mem)
{
    string original_memID = original_mem;
    int retValue = 0;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection mCon = new SqlConnection())
    {
        mCon.ConnectionString = ConStr;
        try
        {
            mCon.Open();
            using (SqlCommand mCom = new SqlCommand())
            {
                mCom.Connection = mCon;
                mCom.CommandText = "Get_UplinkID";
                mCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memID", memID);
                mCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(mCom);
                da.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && retValue != 1)
                {
                    string n_upid = dt.Rows[0]["uplineId"].ToString();
                    if (n_upid.ToLower() == original_memID.ToLower())
                    {
                        retValue = 1;

                    }
                    else if( n_upid.ToLower() != original_memID.ToLower())
                    {
                        if (n_upid.ToLower() == "self")
                        {
                            retValue = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            checkUplinkID(n_upid, original_memID);  // its coming back here after returning and its returning '0' 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            mCon.Close();
            mCon.Dispose();
        }
    }

    return retValue;

}
```

Now the problem is after the `retValue = 1` it's returning but it's going back to the  `checkUplinkID` function and making `retValue = 0` and returning it.
so what should I do?

And I am calling this function in a `aspx.cs` page, like this:

```
 int getchk = iobj.checkUplinkID(memid, memberId);
```

Where `iobj` is object of the class where that method is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely want to assign the return value of `checkUplinkID` to `retValue`:

```
else
{
    retValue = checkUplinkID(n_upid, original_memID);  // its coming back here after returning and its returning '0' 
}
```

Oh, and your `catch` block is very bad style:
It doesn't do anything except removing the original stack trace, so you will have no info on where the exception originally originated from. Just remove that `catch` block.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, the result of the recursive call is not used. You need to store the value:

```
retValue = checkUplinkID(n_upid, original_memID);
```

Otherwise, the result of the recursive call is not used and the `retValue` of the "outermost" method call remains 0.

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting a basic concept of recursion, the BASE case, that is where the recursion stops and go back resolving all the other calls. That's why your recursion didn't stop;